# Having trouble deciphering a sentence tokenizer regex

Tags: regex, tokenize

The following regex is suppose to act as a sentence tokenizer pattern, but I'm having some trouble deciphering what exactly it's doing:

`(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<![A-Z]\.)(?<=\.|\?|\!)\s`

I understand that it's using positive and negative lookbehinds, as the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) explains (they give the example of a negative lookbehind like this: `(?<!B)A`). But what is considered `A` in the above regex?

Comment: The `A` is `\s` at the end. Note that the positive lookbehind can be written as `(?<=[.?!])` using a character class. If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, you could shorten it making the `[a-z]` optional `(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]?\.)(?<=[.?!])\s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is checking for breaks between sentences. The negative lookbehinds prevent false matches that represent abbreviations instead of the ends of sentences. They mean:

- `(?<!\w\.\w.)` Don't match anything that looks like A.b., 2.c., or 1.3. (Probably they meant for the second period to also be `\.` to match only a period, but as written it will match any character at the end, for example A.b! or g.Z4)
- `(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)` Don't match anything that looks like Cf., Dr., Mr., etc. Note this only checks two characters, so "Mrs." will be matched incorrectly.
- `(?<![A-Z]\.)` Don't match anything that looks like A. or C.

Then if these all pass, it has a positive lookbehind `(?<=\.|\?|\!)` to check for `.`, `?` or `!`.

And finally it matches on any whitespace `\s`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gaNnEQ/1)